GUI file copy stalls to HDD Enclosure. ROBOCOPY fine
I have this 2.5” SATA HDD/SSD USB 3 enclosure. It’s just purchased in Mar-24.
https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0BG62HMDJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
I tested it on my Toshiba 1 TB SATA 2.5” HDD.
I have a strange observation. When from Windows explorer (Windows 10 as well as 11) when I copy a very large file say 5 GB sized ISO file for example, then midway the transfer rate drops to 0. Then explorer hangs the enclosure goes not responding and I have to physically disconnect it and reconnect again. File copy fails. Same is the case with other file sync apps like Free File Sync. I have the latest version.
However if I use ROBOCOPY command line to copy same large files then it works flawlessly.
What is wrong with GUI based file copy operation?
There’s no issue with GUI based file copy from one internal drive to another. The issue only comes when this enclosure is the destination.
The enclosure is connected directly to USB 3 port of my Windows 11 desktop PC or Windows 10 Laptop. No extension cables are ever used here.

Edit 1 -
As per below answer, by default it was already on Quick removal for the USB enclosure. I as well temporarily enabled Better performance and unchecked Write caching and set it back to Quick removal. The issue still persists. Later I am also going to try with Live Linux boot and check if it still hangs when different OS is in picture.

Edit 2 -
Copying works flawlessly (huge files as well) when done from within Live Linux Mint 21. I got constant 90 - 100 MB/S and it never dropped to 0 at all.  I tried 3 - 4 times again & again and it never dropped to 0 at all.
The SMART of the HDD in question is GOOD. No issues at all.
ROBOCOPY was set to only one retry /R:1 /W:1

Perhaps the PC is caching writes while using the Windows Explorer GUI. During the delay in writing (i.e., the PC is still reading from internal drive, but has not written yet to the external yet), that external drive goes to sleep. To prove that point, use Explorer to copy that 5 GB file from the USB drive to the internal, and it should succeed, if my presumption is correct, because the USB drive is being kept awake by continual reads.
If that is the case, then try turning off write caching, as shown below.

In Removal policy, select Quick removal
or

In Write-caching policy, remove the check-mark from Enable write-caching... (note that it is grayed in the image, because Quick removal defeats caching).



There might be a small penalty in write speed, or not, but the impact should be small.
Another way to prevent the drive from sleeping is with a utility such as KeepAliveHD or an alternative. That said, it does seem a bit odd that Windows would need such a workaround.

Thank you for your answer. +1 from me. By default it was already on Quick removal for the USB enclosure. I as well temporarily enabled Better performance and unchecked Write caching and set it back to Quick removal. The issue still persists. Later I am also going to try with Live Linux boot and check if it still hangs when different OS is in picture.

@rajeev, sorry that didn't help. One more thing to try in Windows would be a utility such as KeepAliveHD, https://github.com/stsrki/KeepAliveHD, or an alternative, https://alternativeto.net/software/keepalivehd/, which will be added to answer. An your idea of testing under Linux is excellent.
